# Lacking permissions for other users when saving QGIS 3 project on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, windows-10, qgs, permissionerror

When saving a project under QGIS 3.x on a local Windows PC under e.g. `c:\tmp` another user logged on to the PC cannot open the project due to lacking permissions. The project file saved from QGIS 3 permissions are restricted to groups **SYSTEM** and **Admin** and for the **current user**:

[image]

Project files saved under QGIS 2.x have in addition full access for groups **User** and **Everyone**:

[image]

Changing permissions for the target folder (`c:\tmp`) has no affect. Remarkable: This behavior does not apply to i.e. Layer definitions saved from QGIS 3, these have the same permissions as project files saved from QGIS 2 (cp. above screenshot).

Is this a bug or a feature or am I missing any settings?

Comment: After setting the target folder permissions, **new** files saved in this directory should inherit the folder permissions.

Comment: @JGH That's what I expect, but then the permissions for QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 project files shouldn't differ, but they do. And as I stated above, changes in the target folders permissions have no effect :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that catches the `QgsProject.projectSaved` signal and creates a batch file and executes it:

```py
import os
from qgis.core import QgsProject

bat_tmp = """@echo off
             set quelle="path_to_qgz"
             icacls %quelle% /grant Jeder:(CI)(OI)(F)
             pause
          """

def setPermissions():
    
    qgs_path = os.path.normpath(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
    batch_path = os.path.normpath('c:\\tmp\\permissions.bat')
    
    with open(batch_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(bat_tmp.replace('path_to_qgz', qgs_path))
    
    os.system(batch_path)

QgsProject.instance().projectSaved.connect(setPermissions)
```

This can be executed from python console editor or putted in a startup-script.